# shiny - interactive ggplot with subset

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to R&shiny. I'd like to make a shiny app that the plot can be interactive with subset I choose, but ggplot cannot work with warning

> Error in ouptut$Trendplot <- renderPlot({ : object 'ouptut' not found

It will be really appreciated if you can help to figure it works.

The following is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

   # Application title
   headerPanel("Pre-report situation"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
      sidebarPanel(selectizeInput("DMS", "DMS:", choices = unique(datass$DMS)
      )),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption")),
      plotOutput("Trendplot"))
   )
datass <- read.csv("C:/Users/yyu6/Documents/PR.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   formulaText <- reactive({
    input$DMS  })

   datasetInput <- reactive({
     selection <- Input$DMS
     subset(datass, DMS == selection)
   })

  output$caption <- renderText({formulaText()
   })

  ouptut$Trendplot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(datasetInput(), mapping = aes(x=DMS))+geom_histogram(stat = "count")
  })
   }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Possibly caused by your typo of `ouptut$Trendplot` instead of `output$Trendplot`

Comment: oh~yeah, thank you. 
But there is another problem here: 
"Warning: Error in <reactive:datasetInput>: object 'Input' not found"

Comment: Same kind of problem: you need lower-case "i" `input`, not upper-case "I" `Input`.

Comment: ！！！ It does work. Thank you guys. I really need to notice my typo. Thank you both again.